# Decrease the space between subfloats inside a float environment

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am using the code below to place images side by side and under each other, but this results in a big space between the first two images (see the screenshot at the end). I want to make the images bigger and reduce the space between them. I tried to scale them differently, but it did not decrease the space but placed them differently.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{img/A.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{img/B.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{img/C.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: `\hfill` means use as much space as possible delete that (don't leave a blank line)

Comment: or change `{0.4\textwidth}` to say `{0.47\textwidth}`

Comment: or instead of `\hfill` use `\hfil` (one `l` only).

Comment: @Zarko What is the difference?

Comment: Just made short test and see difference :-). `hfil` doesn't push image appart to text block borders but make equal distances between images and and images and text block borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `subfigure` if you don't have subcaptions.

With `\hfill` between the first two images, you push them flush to the margin.

If you use `\hfil` (be careful with endlines that become spaces, though), you get equal spaces at left and right as in the middle, because `\centering` implicitly adds `\hfil` to either side.

Alternatively, use an explicit space such as `\quad`.

Note that I added blank lines and `\bigskip` between the first two images and the last one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% not for the production version

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}

\caption{Three figures}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\quad
\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}

\caption{Three figures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is used just to show the boundaries of the text block.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wasn't really sure what the code I used actually did. I just found it on StackExchange when I was looking for a way how to put images side by side and it caused me some trouble. But now I understand it better.